# IDE for GNAT 3.15p Ada compiler

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

I am using the GNAT 3.15p Ada compiler which is suggested for RTRT. I was using GPS IDE with another version of the GNAT Ada compiler. Is there any IDE available for the GNAT 3.15p compiler? Can I use GPS IDE itself, if so how to change the compiler?

Thanks
Padmapriya

Comment: Is this on Windows? What is "RTRT"?

Comment: I'm assuming some class, but questioners would do better to assume we aren't all familiar with the jargon used around their campus.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that GPS will use the first `gcc` and `gnatmake` that it finds on the `PATH`.

Normally, installing GNAT on Windows will set up the PATH properly; if you already have a later GNAT+GPS installed, installing 3.15p should put itself first on the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

The latest GPS you can find (e.g. GPS from GNAT GPL 2012) might support GNAT 3.15p (although the officially stated support only goes back as far as GNAT Pro 3.16a1). Look in the newer GPS manual for the "multiple toolchains" feature. This works very well for using a newer GNAT toolset with an older compiler. The "multiple toolchains" settings  will override the OS path variable settings.

See http://docs.adacore.com/gps-docs/users_guide/_build/html/compilation.html#working-with-two-compilers

If you use gpr files you will probably have to restrict yourself to project file features that were available in GNAT 3.15p.

You might also have some luck with either GNATbench on Eclipse or AdaGIDE as alternate IDEs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the combination both the answers and it works fine. I installed GPS IDE in C drive and GANT3.15p compiler in D drive. In GPS tool chains configuration provided the compiler path as D:\GNAT\bin and unchecked the options for multiple tool chains. This made GPS to take GNAT3.15p compiler.